# update non-existing document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to create a new document instead of getting an error when trying to update a non-existing document in elasticsearch? I know I could check first but I would love to save that one additional call per document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kimchy has implemented upsert(update-insert) in latest release 0.19.5 
Please refer to [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2008) for more details